# reactjs table render - how to handle empty rows rendering for tbody

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to ReactJS and playing around to learn its tricks of the trade.  I am trying to create a simple table with thead and tbody.

my code looks as below:

```
/**
 * creates a HTML table to show requirements
 **/
var ReqTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

    var rows = []; 
    rows = this.props.data.map(function(row) {
      return ( <ReqRow row={row} />);
    }); 

    return(
      <table className="reqTable table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>REQ #</th>
        <th>Short Desc</th>
        <th>Long Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> {rows} </tbody>
      </table>
    );  
  }
});
```

I am using ajax call to get the rows and render this table.  This works fine overall, but gives a warning in the browser console, indicating that you cannot add a span inside a tbody.

[image]

I am sure I am not adding a span.  But what I believe is that when there are no rows (when render is first time called), it seems reactJS is trying to render a span inside the tbody.

So, should I put an if check here to avoid rendering a span?  Finally what is the correct way to render a empty set of rows in tbody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you have space characters as children of your `tbody` element, before and after your `rows` array:

```
<tbody> {rows} </tbody>
```

Compiles to:

```
React.createElement("tbody", null, " ", rows, " ");
```

Because of DOM limitations, when a DOM component has more than one child, React wraps all its text children within `<span>` elements. So the above JSX is equivalent to:

```
<tbody><span> </span>{rows}<span> </span></tbody>
```

To fix this, just remove the extraneous characters:

```
<tbody>{rows}</tbody>
```